# What are the limits of Libre when publishing open access controversial books?

Tags: law, publishing

We're living in [freedom of speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_speech) community.
However when writing controversial books, are there any topics which are not allowed to write about in First World countries (even for educational purposes)? How do you know when you cross the line?

One example could be [Uncle Fester books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Fester_(author)) or WikiLeaks which are the borderlines I think. Are there any other examples?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about freedom (of speech) and not Free/Libre/Open content. Or differently put, Free as opposed to proprietary.

Comment: This question would likely be a better fit over at [law.SE], but might already have been answered there. I'm not a contributing member over there, so I wouldn't know.

Comment: If our site is going to change to [Free/Libre/Open](http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/a/571/407) (with broader scope), I don't see how this is off-topic. Which simple asks which topics are not allowed for open access Libre resource (such as e-book), but the same could apply to source code.

Comment: no one said anything about a broader scope, and even if they did, nothing has been definitely decided yet. Wethera book is Libre or not has nothing to do with which topics you are allowed to write about. This is a matter of free speech laws.

Comment: This appears to be a question about criminal law; can you get busted for publishing a bomb-building manual. FLO(ss) seems wildly beside the point.

Comment: I think that questions about the interaction of FLO with other things, including laws, are on-topic, inasmuch as they can be answered by a non-lawyer

Comment: @d3vid an argument could be made there, but there is definitely a line; in this case there is no interaction.

Comment: Re-posted at [Law SE](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/1962/529).

Comment: @kenorb our site is not changing to have a broader scope. We're just trying to find a name that does not imply a narrower scope than we have. Free/Libre/Open probably makes our scope seem broader than it is and it's only one potential name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FLO licenses take a legal, copyright-restricted-by-default work, and give you permission to copy, modify and/or distribute that work. They would not take precedence over criminal law in your country, including laws that criminalise or restrict publication and distribution of certain materials.

Comment: An interesting side-effect could be that they give someone else the rights to publish your book elsewhere. This might just fulfill the original goal of getting the book published.